# How to find original copied git branch name from current git branch in repository?

Tags: git

How would you read the name of the branch that was copied to create the currently checked out branch?

For current branch name there is:

```
git symbolic-ref HEAD
```

Assuming the current branch started as a copy from another branch, sometimes called a **clone** of another branch, how is the name of that branch found?

Comment: Consider not using the term clone when referring to “copying” branches. In git, cloning is the act of making a copy of another repo.

Comment: I agree - Tortoise Git has a 'Show Reflog' dialog that shows the copied branch name, and calls the Action 'clone'. How do they find that reference id?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have not changed any of the default settings, and are not doing something weird, the name of the branch in the *other* Git is usually the *same* as the name of the branch in your own Git.  That is, *your* `master` relates to *their* `master`, which you call `origin/master`.

There are no guarantees, though: if you create a new branch named `xyzzy` without checking whether they have a branch also named `xyzzy`, your `xyzzy` may have no relationship to their `xyzzy`, nor to your `origin/xyzzy` if you have one.

#### Background

You don't exactly clone *branches;* you clone entire *repositories*.

The URL you passed to `git clone` for the repository you just cloned is stored under the *remote* name you choose.  If you did not choose one, Git will use its built-in default, `origin`, and hence the URL from which you cloned is stored under `remote.origin.url`:

```
$ git config --get remote.origin.url
<url>
```

You *can* restrict which branch name(s) your clone process examines.  Note, however, that these branch names are as found on in some *other* Git (at the URL you specify): they are not your own branch names.  The default is to use *all* the branch names that the other Git lists.  That is, your Git connects, via the URL, to some other Git, and has the other Git list all its branches, all its tags, and all the other names it can list:

```
$ git ls-remote <url>
```

If this is applied to, say, `git://github.com/git/git`, the output is quite long:

```
$ git ls-remote git://github.com/git/git
b7bd9486b055c3f967a870311e704e3bb0654e4f        HEAD
53f9a3e157dbbc901a02ac2c73346d375e24978c        refs/heads/maint
b7bd9486b055c3f967a870311e704e3bb0654e4f        refs/heads/master
5c9ce644c390ec4ef3ba4adc94e7f4af17ade36b        refs/heads/next
1aaaa8cf15ba4eb62d485c5c8b64d6a75b9e7c3f        refs/heads/pu
f59de5ad04b18866024fb298ddb276cb51d91673        refs/heads/todo
[lots of text snipped]
8d091e9ed473c372a5b89d1258d1c3ad01daa04c        refs/tags/v2.9.4
d61226c1118f749280c050555d83560ca0f3bf71        refs/tags/v2.9.4^{}
dcba104ffdcf2f27bc5058d8321e7a6c2fe8f27e        refs/tags/v2.9.5
4d4165b80d6b91a255e2847583bd4df98b5d54e1        refs/tags/v2.9.5^{}
```

These are all the names that *their* Git is willing to export.  Your Git takes those names and modifies the ones that were branch names—that started with `refs/heads/`—to create your *remote-tracking names*, replacing `refs/heads/` with `refs/remotes/origin/` (assuming you are using the default remote name `origin`).

At this point, then, your clone has:

```
refs/remotes/origin/maint
refs/remotes/origin/master
```

and so on, plus any tags (copied straight through: `refs/tags/v2.12.0` remains named `refs/tags/v2.12.0`) depending on what you asked your Git to retain from their Git.

#### How your Git creates new branches

When all of this downloading is complete, the last thing that `git clone` does is direct your own Git to check out some particular commit—usually by a branch name.  You may choose which name your Git should use, but if you don't, your Git uses their Git's direction to pick one, typically `master`.  Your Git does not yet *have* such a branch, but your Git *does* have the *remote-tracking name* `origin/master` (short for `refs/remotes/origin/master`).  So your Git now *creates* your own branch `master`—`refs/heads/master` being its full name—using the same commit hash ID your Git just saved as that for `origin/master`.  In the example above, that's `b7bd9486b055c3f967a870311e704e3bb0654e4f`.

Git calls this "DWIM" or Do What I Mean: you ask your Git to check out some existing branch name, but you *don't have that branch name* yet.  So your Git probes through your *remote-tracking* names to see if there is one that matches.  There needs to be exactly one such match: if so, Git creates your name, pointing to the same commit as your remote-tracking name.

If you use `git checkout -b name` or `git branch name`, however, to create a new branch named *`name`*, your Git does not have to find a remote-tracking name.  Your Git simply creates that name right now, pointing to the current commit, regardless of whether there is some similar remote-tracking name.

#### All of this is controllable

All of this fancy renaming is under your own control, through the *fetch refspecs*.  If you have made a standard clone with the standard remote name `origin`, and you run:

```
$ git config --get remote.origin.fetch
```

you will get one line of output reading:

```
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

This is a *refspec* and it controls the default behavior of `git fetch origin`: your Git will call up the other Git at `remote.origin.url`, get the same listing of names we saw with `git ls-remote` above, and match up the branch names to the `refs/heads/*` part of this pair.  It will then rewrite each of those names to the right-hand-side `refs/remotes/origin/*`, with the `*` part being replaced by whatever was matched earlier.  That's the mechanism by which their `master` becomes your `origin/master`, and so on.

Some clone options, especially `--single-branch`, change this default refspec.  You can also replace it manually.  There's rarely a good reason to do that—the default is usually right.  If you are going to do that, read up on refspecs.

Comment: Maybe the term **clone** is incorrect. 
When a have a repository and create a branch from another branch in the same repository. Often call is a 'clone' branch.

If using tortoise git it does have a nice dialog that lists and commits back until the branch was created. (Maybe created is the right term)

Thank you for the very detailed reply!!!

Comment: Then tortoise git uses an incorrect term. You can tell if branches have the same merge base, or if they point to the same commit, but not which was a clone of what.